# run javascript continuously on a url

Tags: javascript

I need to fill form in a web page with change in username each time. I am allowed to take usernames as numbers. I was able to figure out filling out form using developers tool with some javascript:

```
document.getElementById('user_name').value = '111';
document.getElementById('first_name').value = 'a';
document.getElementById('last_name').value = 'a';
```

but now I need to fill about 100 forms and I don't want to do it manually everytime from developers console. Is there anyway I can achieve this using script?

How can I pass this javascript to a url repeatedly and with increase in user_name value.

New to html/javascript. I hope I dont sound dumb!!!

Comment: You could host your script file in some server an then bookmarked that script in the browser, then you only need to click the bookmark when you are in the desire site.

Comment: What are you trying to do? hAcKingG!